# Google Drive OAuth2 Authentification with visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net, oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to develop an Visual Basic .net console application to download and convert files from GoogleDrive. So far it worked perfectly while OAuth was available. But now its not working anymore. I googled for similar Programs and found multiple code working with the following solution.

There is a problem after I adapted their concept to my code: A Google Api Class is missing in the OAuth2 Namespace. Now the weird part is that the documentation (yes for my used dll version) of the Google OAuth Api says that this class must exist. But its not there. I also tried it in CSharp but the class keeps missing.

To download the Google Api's I used nuget.

My Code:

```
Imports Google.Apis
Imports Google.Apis.Auth
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services

Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Extensions
Imports Google.GData.Spreadsheets

Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Sub DownloadFile(strUsr As String, strPwd As String, strGoogleFileId As String, strTargetFile As String, strFormatId As String, boolDebug As Boolean)
    Try
        Dim strServiceUrl As String = "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"
        Dim strRequestUrl As String = strServiceUrl + "/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + strGoogleFileId + "&exportFormat=" + strFormatId
        Dim query As New SpreadsheetQuery(strRequestUrl)
        Dim ssservice As New SpreadsheetsService("GoogleDriveDownloader_AppDesigners_de")

        Login(strUsr, strPwd, ssservice, LoginMode.OAuth2)

        Dim Stream As Stream = ssservice.Query(New Uri(strRequestUrl))
        Dim fStream As New FileStream(strTargetFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        Stream.CopyTo(fStream)
        fStream.Flush()
        fStream.Close()

        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded GoogleSpreadSheet with Id '" + strGoogleFileId + "' to File '" + strTargetFile + "'")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message)
        If boolDebug Then
            Console.WriteLine("Source: " + ex.Source)
            Console.WriteLine("Call Stack: " + ex.StackTrace)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Enum LoginMode
    OAuth1
    OAuth2
End Enum

Sub Login(strUsr As String, strPwd As String, ssservice As SpreadsheetsService, mode As LoginMode)
    If mode = LoginMode.OAuth1 Then
        LoginOAuth1(strUsr, strPwd, ssservice)
    ElseIf mode = LoginMode.OAuth2 Then
        LoginOAuth2(strUsr, strPwd, ssservice)
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoginOAuth2(strUsr As String, strPwd As String, ssservice As SpreadsheetsService)
    Dim strServiceUrl As String = "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"

    Dim strServiceEmail As String = "<mygoogleacc>"
    Dim certificate As New X509Certificate2("d:\GoogleDriveConverter\cert.p12",
                                            "<certpwd>",
                                            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)

    Dim credentialInitializer As New ServiceAccountCredential(New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(strServiceEmail))

    credentialInitializer.User = strUsr
    credentialInitializer.Scopes = New String() {strServiceUrl}

    Dim credential As New ServiceAccountCredential(credentialInitializer.FromCertificate(certificate))

    If (Not credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result) Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Access token request failed.")
    End If

    Dim requestFactory = New GDataRequestFactory("GoogleDriveDownloader_AppDesigners_de")
    requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + credential.Token.AccessToken)
    ssservice.RequestFactory = requestFactory
End Sub

Sub LoginOAuth1(strUsr As String, strPwd As String, ssservice As SpreadsheetsService)
    ssservice.setUserCredentials(strUsr, strPwd)
End Sub
```

(OAuth2 Authification based on http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/OAuth2GoogleServiceAccounts.html)

Compiling fails with this exception:

> The type or namespace name 'ServiceAccountCredential' could not be found >(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I added all References correctly and nothing is marked as unresolveable except the ServiceAccountCredential Class.

References:

> Google.Apis | 1.9.0.26011 | D:\GoogleDriveConverter\Google.Apis.1.9.0\lib\net40\Google.Apis.dll
>
> Google.Apis.Auth | 1.9.0.26011 | D:\GoogleDriveConverter\Google.Apis.Auth.1.9.0\lib\net40\Google.Apis.Auth.dll
>
> Google.GData.Client | 2.2.0.0 | D:\GoogleDriveConverter\Redist\Google.GData.Client.dll
>
> Google.GData.Extensions | 2.2.0.0 | D:\GoogleDriveConverter\Redist\Google.GData.Extensions.dll
>
> Google.GData.Spreadsheets | 2.2.0.0 | D:\GoogleDriveConverter\Redist\Google.GData.Spreadsheets.dll
>
> System | 4.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll
>
> System.Core | 4.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll
>
> System.Data | 4.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll
>
> System.Data.DataSetExtensions | 4.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
>
> System.Deployment | 4.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Deployment.dll
>
> System.Xml | 4.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll
>
> System.Xml.Linq | 4.0.0.0 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll

The Class description for ServiceAccountCredential can be found here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1ServiceAccountCredential

Another strange thing is that the class ServiceCredential which should be extended by ServiceAccountCredential exists.

So what can I do to clear this problem or alternativly what can be done to get a valid OAuth2 verfication with GoogleDrive in my Program without using that specific class?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending hours to find out what I did wrong or why anybody else never heard of the problem I finally found out that there was a problem with the nuget package I downloaded with the console version of nuget. In order to fix the Problem you first need the newest Visual Studio 2015 Version and then use the Buildin Nuget Package Manager to add Google.Apis.Auth. After this the above mentioned Code will magically work as it should have in the first place. Hope I can help someone else dealing with the same problem.